# How to avoid Double Brace Initialization (DBI) with MultilineRecursiveToStringStyle

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
    @Override public String toString() {
    return new ReflectionToStringBuilder(this, new MultilineRecursiveToStringStyle() {
        {
            setUseShortClassName(true);
            setUseIdentityHashCode(false);
        }
    }).build();
}
```

As you can see, Double Brace Initialization (DBI) is used. How can I change this code so that I'm not using DBI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first understand [*what* double brace initialisation actually does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27521360/5133585). According to the linked answer, the main drawback of DBI that applies here is that it can create a lot of anonymous classes without you noticing, because the syntax is so lightweight.

According to the documentation, the methods you want to call, like [`setUseIdentityHashCode`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringStyle.html#setUseIdentityHashCode-boolean-) are `protected`, so in order to access it, we ***must*** create a subclass of `MultilineRecursiveToStringStyle`. It doesn't really matter whether you do that with DBI to create an anonymous class:

```
public static final ToStringStyle MY_CUSTOM_STYLE = new MultilineRecursiveToStringStyle() {{
    setUseIdentityHashCode(false);
    setUseShortClassName(true);
}};

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new ReflectionToStringBuilder(this, MY_CUSTOM_STYLE).build();
}
```

or by writing a named class:

```
class MyCustomStyle extends MultilineRecursiveToStringStyle {
    private MyCustomStyle() {
        setUseIdentityHashCode(false);
        setUseShortClassName(true);
    }

    public static final MyCustomStyle INSTANCE = new MyCustomStyle();
}

...

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new ReflectionToStringBuilder(this, MyCustomStyle.INSTANCE).build();
}
```

Note that in both cases, I only create *one* new class and one single instance of that class. I put that instance in a static final field, and reuse the static final field whenever I can.

By doing this, you wouldn't end up creating 100 `MultilineRecursiveToStringStyle` subclasses if you want to override `toString` 100 times using the same style, which you would have done if you repeated the DBI 100 times.